# Is there any relationship between topological and graphical connectedness?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

We have two ideas of contentedness from two different branches of mathematics - *Topology* and *Graph Theory*. One talks about the connectedness of a space and another about a graph. **But does there exist any relation between these seemingly isolated concepts of connectedness?** I apologize if the question appears too silly for MSE.

Comment: You might find this Wikipedia section useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Graphs

Comment: Or also this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_graph_theory).  In short, we can make a graph into a topological space and in that setting graph connectedness is the same as topological connectedness.